# Is question about user interface optimization on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, site-rec

I have made dialog box that hosts a lot of various controls ( around 50 ) using C++ and raw WinAPI.

Although my application works, I still wish to somehow reduce the number of controls I use in a dialog box. I wish to ask on Programmers for help, so I first wanted to check here if this type of question is on topic?

If it isn't can you suggest me SE network that could help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Man, I just want to say thanks for asking.  So many people (myself included) just post and hope for the best.  You've shown a level of consideration for the community that is apparently rare for September.

Comment: @MetaFight: I know how hard it is for the community to spare some time to genuinely help *for free*. I believe the least we can do is invest effort into phrasing our questions, thus making things easier. Best regards :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds more like a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). You have working code, but want to improve it, so it's not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Programmers is really for questions you'd have at the start of the process - design decisions, requirements gathering, architecture etc.

If you do decide to post on Code Review check out their help pages and look at other questions first to make sure you get your question right.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff A version of your question could also fit [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). If you're looking for ways to organize those 50 controls in a way that won't make your users cry, for example. (Not a regular on the site, do drop by their [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/ux-chat) and make sure such a question would be on topic there first)

Comment: My understanding is asking about the dialog layout would be on-topic at UX, but discussing the code that makes it work would be off-topic.